# JavaScript canvas drawing at wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've got a canvas in HTML and when I draw on it when the browser window is at my standard size it works fine however when you start to scale the window (i.e shrink it), the drawing on the canvas doesn't appear where it's meant to.

```js
var mousePressed = false;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var lastX;
var lastY;
var colour = "black";
var size = 3;


function clear1() {
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}


canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", (function(e) {
  var xpos = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var ypos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  mousePressed = true;

  draw(xpos, ypos, false);
}));

canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", (function(e) {
  mousePressed = false;
}));

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (function(e) {
  var xpos = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  var ypos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  if (mousePressed) {
    draw(xpos, ypos, true);
  }

}));



function draw(x, y, isDown) {
  if (isDown) {
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = colour;
    context.lineWidth = size;
    context.lineJoin = "round";
    context.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
  }
  lastX = x;
  lastY = y;

}
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100">

</canvas>

<button onclick="clear1()" type="Submit1">Clear</button>

<input name="Submit" id="submitButton" type="submit" onclick="sendPayment()" value="Send Payment">
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I've done that :)

Comment: I've fixed the stack snippets / code block thing for you.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on Chrome, Firefox, and IE11. Zooming with `Ctrl+` and `Ctrl-` zooms, and drawing still tracks my cursor, whether I've shrunk or expanded the view.

Comment: Don't set canvas width/height through CSS, use it's own width and height properties directly

Answer (score 1):

From [Kaiido's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577591/javascript-canvas-drawing-at-wrong-coordinates/37220919#comment56901169_34577591):

> Don't set canvas width/height through CSS, use it's own width and height properties directly